# What will happen with $T(x,y)$ if there is an injective conformal mapping $f$ that maps $(x, y)$ into $(u, v)$?

Tags: quasiconformal-maps, conformal-field-theory

Currently, I have solved the temperature equation and I obtained the values $T(x, y)$ in the xy-space. I would like to map the xy-space onto the uv-space conformally and injective (that means that a point $(x_p, y_p)$ will map one-to-one on $(u_p, v_p)$). What will happen with the temperature value $\tilde{T}(u_{p}, v_{p})$? Will it be equal to $T(x_p, y_p)$, $ T(x_p, y_p)$ multiplied by a factor or something else?

The conformal mapping that I want to use is the Schwarz-Christoffel transformation that maps an unit disk onto a polygon.

Comment: No, of course you use the composition of functions. Do not use $T$ for two different functions, although we standardly do this in beginning calculus. If $(u,v)=\phi(x,y)$, then you’re looking at $\tilde T(u,v) = T(\phi^{-1}(u,v))$.

Comment: @TedShifrin based on your comment, I assume that the temperature in $(u, v)$ will be equal to the temperature in $(x, y)$?

Comment: What does that even mean?

Comment: Now that you rewrote the question, the answer is that for any given $p$, yes, $\tilde T(u_p,v_p)=T(x_p,y_p)$. The formula I wrote earlier is what you need.